# Perl giving errors on array reference

Tags: arrays, perl

Could someone explain how to correctly reference the arrays @names and @numbers. Currently I am getting warnings saying that using @names->[$count] is deprecated. I've looked around and people said to do $names->[$count] however when I do this it says that $names / $numbers does not exist.

```
my $ldap = Lib::Phonebook->new();

my (@names, @numbers, $count, $name_number_count);

    @names             = $ldap->list_telephone_account_names();

    @numbers           = $ldap->list_telephone_account_numbers();

    $name_number_count = @names;

    $count = 0;

    for $count (0 .. $name_number_count) {
        print @names->[$count] . " -> " . @numbers->[$count] . "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@names` is an array, so to access an element you would use `$names[$index]`.

Also, iterating from `0 .. $name_number_count` will take you over the end of the array.  You want 0 through "the last element index in @names" which would be `@names - 1` or `$#names`.  So:

```
for my $count (0 .. $#names) {
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! just noticed I'm now getting this: `Use of uninitialized value within @names in concatenation (.)` is this as a result of using this or something unrelated? Just seen your edit, thanks a lot that's sorted it